# javascript playing a sound as if it came from the left

Tags: javascript, audio, orientation

I am programming a script with tampermoneky for blind users to be able to play a card game.

To help the user allocate which player is playing a card I want to play a little with stereo and make it as if the sound came from the left or the right.

```
 BUI_sounds.g.h = new Audio(BUI_audioPath + BUI_audioPathG + "Hearts.wav");
 BUI_sounds.g["5"] = new Audio(BUI_audioPath + BUI_audioPathG + "Five.wav");

var suit= "h";
var rank= 5;
 BUI_scheduleSound(BUI_sounds.g[suit]);
 BUI_scheduleSound(BUI_sounds.g[rank]);

function BUI_scheduleSound(sound){
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getTime();
    if (n< BUI_audiofinnish)
    {//sounds scheduled didn't finnish yet
        setTimeout(function() {
            BUI_readSound(sound);
        }, BUI_audiofinnish - n);
        BUI_audiofinnish += (sound.duration*1000);
    }
    else{
        sound.play();
        BUI_audiofinnish = n + (sound.duration*1000);
    }
}

function BUI_readSound(sound){
   sound.play();
}
```

The above code would play "Hearts.wav" inmediately and schedule "Five.wav" to be played when it is finished, what modifications would I need to do for the sounds to be played as if coming from the left?